# Parse an Ics file from outlook using python

Tags: python, parsing, icalendar, webdav, alteryx

Hello I am currently working on a project where I extract an ics file from a certain group calendar in outlook using my webdav server then need to parse it so I can get readable dates ,events,PTO or OOO events for the team members.

Now I am trying to automate this so it can run daily but I am having trouble getting the right configuration in python to parse my file and if there is a better way of extracting it from outlook I would be happy to hear it....I was using alteryx with a built in outlook extract tool where it would give me a csv file or JSON to work with and it was great but it has stopped working since.

**Tried using this "[Python with ICS files and CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911600/python-with-ics-files-and-csv)" and modifying it to fit my needs but I havent used python in a while and in need of help**

[image: ics data fields]

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can use help constructing  a line of code like the one referenced in the link to parse out the ics file into something understandable like a csv with dates,events , PTO and OOO times.

Comment: The way stack works is you show your code to demonstrate that you have tried and describe the problem you are having.  The way your question reads now, it sounds like you want the code done for you.